# Returning a 'calculated' column in an SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query: `'SELECT MatchID, ScoreHome, ScoreAway FROM Match'` which returns data as follows:

```
MatchID ScoreHome   ScoreAway
1       0           0
2       1           3
3       1           3
4       2           0
5       3           1
```

I need to identify what the result of the contest was and return the Result as an additional column like this:

```
MatchID ScoreHome   ScoreAway   Result
    1       0           0       The Draw
    2       1           3       Away Win
    3       1           3       Away Win
    4       2           0       Home Win
    5       3           1       Home Win
```

I've been trying to work out how to use the CASE command to do this, without success. So far I have something like this:

```
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(8)
SELECT CASE @result 
           WHEN (ScoreHome > ScoreAway) THEN "Home Win"
           WHEN (ScoreHome < ScoreAway) THEN "Away Win"
           ELSE "The Draw"
       END 
  FROM Match
```

But this gives me `'Incorrect syntax near '>'`.' That may be completely the wrong thing to try to do but I'm very new to this. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to declare any variables to achieve what you want :

```
SELECT 
   MatchID,
   ScoreHome, 
   ScoreAway,
   (CASE WHEN (ScoreHome > ScoreAway) THEN 'Home Win'
         WHEN (ScoreHome < ScoreAway) THEN 'Away Win'            
         ELSE 'The Draw' END
   ) AS Result
FROM 
   Match
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    *, 
    (case when ScoreHome=ScoreAway then 'The Draw' 
    when ScoreHome<ScoreAway then 'Away Win' 
    else 'Home Win' end) Result
from tbl
```